# How can I change the background image of a div when another div is clicked?

Tags: jquery, css, click, background-image

I'm trying to alter the background-image of one div when another is pressed. I'm using jQuery and have found this for doing so...

```
$('#input_id').click(function() {
  $('#div_id').css('background-image','url')
});
```

However, I need it to do more than just change the background-image of one div, it must also animate a few others.

I am currently using...

```
$('#input_id').click(function() {
$('#div1').animate({
    left: '0px'
}, 600);
$('#div2').animate({
    left: '-100%'
}, 1000);
$('#div3').animate({
    right: '-100px'
}, 200);
$('#div4').animate({
    top: '0px'
}, 600);
});
```

This works fine and does everything I need it to, but when I add this into the list...

```
$('#div5').css({
    'background-image', 'url(../images/backgrounds/background2.png)');
```

It stops working completely. This is my full code...

```
$('#input_id').click(function() {
$('#div1').animate({
    left: '0px'
}, 600);
$('#div2').animate({
    left: '-100%'
}, 1000);
$('#div3').animate({
    right: '-100px'
}, 200);
$('#div4').animate({
    top: '0px'
}, 600);
$('#div5').css({
    'background-image', 'url(../images/backgrounds/background2.png)');
});
```

My CSS background-image code for Div 5 is...

```
#div5 {
...
background-image:url(../images/backgrounds/background1.png);
...
}
```

Can anyone see any reason why this shouldn't work? Have I done something obviously wrong, or missed something out somewhere?

Comment: syntax error in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend not putting the actual css in the jQuery as this can become quite hard to maintain.

Instead use the jQuery to add a class and specify the background property in the css file.

```
$('#div5').addClass("myclass");

.myclass {
    background-image: url(images/backgrounds/background2.png);
}
```

You can then use the removeClass() method to remove it if you need to.

```
$('#div5').removeClass("myclass");
```

Comment: I think this is a better way to handle it, and you can put the class in the markup if needed as a default - or remove the "original" class having the default background image.

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 things...

```
$('#div5').css({
    'background-image': 'url(images/backgrounds/background2.png)'
});
```

Firstly, there was a syntax error at the end of that bit of code (two lots of closing brackets).

Secondly, and this is a pure guess, but your CSS files are likely in a css (or styles) folder.  It would be correct to reference the images folder as `../images` from there, but not from script running in the page.  (Notice I removed the leading `../`).

Comment: either remove the `{` and `}` or replace the `,` with a `:`

Answer (score 2):

You something missed `"});"`

```
    $('#input_id').click(function() {
    $('#div1').animate({
        left: '0px'
    }, 600);
    $('#div2').animate({
        left: '-100%'
    }, 1000);
    $('#div3').animate({
        right: '-100px'
    }, 200);
    $('#div4').animate({
        top: '0px'
    }, 600);
    $('#div5').css({
        'background-image', 'url(../../images/backgrounds/background2.png)');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your

```
$('#div5').css({
    'background-image', 'url(../images/backgrounds/background2.png)');
```

contains a {

```
$('#div5').css('background-image', 'url(../images/backgrounds/background2.png)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#div5').css('background-image', 'url(../images/backgrounds/background2.png)');
```